# WP_cron won't trigger my action

Tags: php, plugins, cron, actions

I'm in a dead end with a schedualed task in a wordpress plugin for a multisite. Somehow the action I added don't get triggered. The task is getting schedualed and returns a timestamp when I run wp_next_scheduled(), but the action itself doesn't go off and trigger the function.

Information that might give some clues:

- It's running on a WPMU-site
- The cronjob is a part of a plugin
- I'm using OOP approach
- The things I'm importing is a custom post type.

*Code Example:*

```
class Cronjobs
{
    function Cronjobs()
    {
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'add_cronjobs'));
    }

    function add_cronjobs()
    {
        add_action('update_properties_daily', array(&$this, 'do_updates'));

        if(!wp_next_scheduled('update_properties_daily') )
        {
           wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'update_properties_daily');
        }
    }

    function do_updates()
    {
        /* Do updates */
    }
}
```

Could really use the help of some wizes on this one, thanks!

---

### UPDATE

Solution: **Create a global function and call that from the custom action.**

Apparently is there some glitch with creating custom actions while refering to an object. Since **custom actions is stored in the DB** (as far as I've understood), **the objected won't be instansiated** and therefor **can't use it's methods**. Therefor: back to basics and use a global function.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not getting called? Try logging something to file as the first line of your action - it may be that it is being called but causing a fatal error before anything useful happens.

Comment: Has a file_put_contents() in the first line, that works when the method is called outside the action. No success, though.  
Thx for the answer, btw.

Comment: Where / when do you instantiate your class? Ensure the action is registered and the class instantiated when wpcron gets fired.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call add_action from outside the class, with a reference to the object. Example:

```
$cj = new Cronjobs;
add_action('update_properties_daily', array(&$cj, 'do_updates'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot **register_activation_hook()**

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: Is that really required? Since I'm running it on _init_ and conditioned the _wp_schedule_event_ to only run only if the job doesn't exists I'd figured it would be working anyway.

Hmm. No can't be it. It _does_ return a timestamp, so the shedualed task exists. It seems like its the action that isn't working.

Comment: I don't think you need to register an activation hook, if you add it, it's registered automatically.